# grunt-preprocess doesn't process code block

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I've read all the docs and all the SO posts I can find regarding grunt-preprocess but am still unable to get this to work. It seems to be a very useful option and help with getting this to work is greatly appreciated.

I have the following in my Gruntfile.js

```
    env: {
        dev: {
            NODE_ENV: 'DEVELOPMENT',
        },
        dist: {
            NODE_ENV: 'PRODUCTION',
        },
    },

    preprocess: {
        dev: {
            options: {
                context: {
                    NODE_ENV: 'DEVELOPMENT'
                },
            },
            files: {
                'app/wp-content/themes/nuvo/footer.php' : 'app/wp-content/themes/nuvo/footer-template.php'
            },
        },
        dist: {
            options: {
                context: {
                    NODE_ENV: 'PRODUCTION'
                },
            },
            files: {
                'dist/wp-content/themes/nuvo/footer.php' : 'app/wp-content/themes/nuvo/footer-template.php'
            },
        },
    },
```

Followed by:

```
grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'clean:dist',
    'env:dev',
    'preprocess:dev',
    'browser_sync',
    'watch',
    'jshint'
]);
```

My footer-template.php file has the following:

```
<!-- @if NODE_ENV == 'DEVELOPMENT' --><!-- @endif -->
<!-- @if NODE_ENV == 'PRODUCTION' -->
<script>
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-*******-*']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
</script>
<!-- @endif -->
```

When I run my default grunt task the footer.php file is generated but nothing is preprocessed, it looks the exact same as the footer-template.php file. Any help on this is much appreciated!

This is what I get when I run grunt --verbose:

```
Running "env:dev" (env) task
Verifying property env.dev exists in config...OK
File: [no files]
Options: (none)

Running "preprocess:dev" (preprocess) task
Verifying property preprocess.dev exists in config...OK
Files: app/wp-content/themes/nuvo/footer-template.php -> app/wp-content/themes/nuvo/footer.php
Verifying property preprocess exists in config...OK
Options: context={"NODE_ENV":"DEVELOPMENT"}
Reading app/wp-content/themes/nuvo/footer-template.php...OK
Writing app/wp-content/themes/nuvo/footer.php...OK
```

Comment: What's the output when you run the task with the `--verbose` flag?

Comment: Good idea @steveax, I added it to the end of my question so it's formatted correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so as a hail mary solution I changed the footer-template file from a .php file to a .html file (still outputting to a .php file) and it worked. I'm guessing grunt-preprocess only parses .html files.

Here's my preprocess grunt task:

```
        preprocess: {
        dev: {
            options: {
                context: {
                    NODE_ENV: 'DEVELOPMENT'
                },
            },
            files: {
                'app/wp-content/themes/nuvo/footer.php' : 'app/wp-content/themes/nuvo/footer-template.html'
            },
        },
        dist: {
            options: {
                context: {
                    NODE_ENV: 'PRODUCTION'
                },
            },
            files: {
                'dist/wp-content/themes/nuvo/footer.php' : 'app/wp-content/themes/nuvo/footer-template.php'
            },
        },
    },
```

And here's the code block in the .html template file:

```
<!-- @if NODE_ENV == 'DEVELOPMENT' --><!-- @endif -->
<!-- @if NODE_ENV == 'PRODUCTION' -->
<script>
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-*******-*']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

    (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
</script>
<!-- @endif -->
```

I no longer need the grunt-env module either, it all work with just the grunt-preprocess module. Hope this saves someone a bunch of time in the future!

Comment: Oh yeah, that could be better documented. The php replacement expects c-style comments assuming the common php use case is within php-only files.

Comment: Feel free to open an issue on github next time, also.

Comment: Ok thanks @jsoverson. I'm not familiar with how to do c-style comments. Maybe you could add examples of comments used for specific file formats to the docs. Love the tool though, great job!